# Common Scrollbar for multiple text area in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, scrollbar

I have 8 text areas in a jsp. How to enable a  common scrollbar (A Horizontal scroll bar) for all 8 text areas?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JSP. You can achieve a similar effect that will synchronize the scrollbars in textareas to a given value by using javascript. You can set the horizontal scrolling amount of a textarea by means of the `scrollLeft` property. The `scrollWidth` property will give you the total scrollable length of each textarea.

You could, for instance, create a slider component using [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), and use its `slide()` method to dynamically change the scroll amount of each textarea to a percentage.

```
<textarea id="textarea1" 
    onscroll="document.getElementById('textarea2').scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;">
    ... some text ... 
</textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2" 
    onscroll="document.getElementById('textarea1').scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;">
    ... some text ... 
</textarea>

<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var val = ui.value/100;
        var t1 = document.getElementById('textarea1');
        t1.scrollLeft = val*t1.scrollWidth;
        var t2 = document.getElementById('textarea2');
        t2.scrollLeft = val*t2.scrollWidth;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

See it working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UA4Nx/4/).

If you don't want to use jQuery, you could also try with an HTML5 `<input type="range">` element. See an example in this [other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UA4Nx/2/).